# Lightbox on wordpress post page

Tags: posts, wp-admin

I am building WordPress admin plugin. In which I have a metabox with 10 checkboxes (It can be more than that). At below there is submit button. My requirement is: 
(A) open a lightbox when some one clicks on submit button. 
(B) In this lightbox I want to show all selected checkbox values with checkboxes. (C) Again, On this  lightbox there would be a submit button. On clicking this form needs to be submitted with selected checkboxes values.

The lightbox will work as confirmation window, 
Any help much appriciated.[image]

Comment: Please attempt the solution, and post some code samples. We'll help out with fixing the issues, but don't expect entire code scripts or tutorials here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before anything... to get a good answer, you need to provide a good question. Code examples would help a lot.

You can use jQuery to accomplish what you need.

Suppose your checkboxes are in a list.

1. You can assign an ID to the list UL.
2. You can use jQuery to run through every element in that list and see if the checkboxes are checked

   $("#checked li:checkbox").each(function(){

   ```
         if($(this).is(':checked')){

             //from here you can put the results found in an array, 
             // or just append to a hidden div that you can target with the lightbox plugin you're using.      

         }

    });
   ```

The idea is to build a hidden DIV that you can use to open as a lightbox. The submit button would have to trigger your form to submit the data to either a table you created in your database, or add it to an existing wordpress table. I hope this helps you get it started.